# Hello, can you help me to add up to 5 list item selections in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, html-lists

So I'm an absolute beginner at JS but would like to have a list a user can select from up to 5 choices, which appear in a separate div. As you can see I've managed to get one to work on click.

```
<ul id="products">
        <li>Bell Box Labels</li>
        <li>Camera Labels</li>
        <li>CCTV Signs</li>
        <li>Certificates & Job Books</li>
        <li>Extinguisher Labels</li>
        <li>Fascia Overlays</li>
        <li>Fire Exit Signage</li>
        <li>Panel Labels</li>
        <li>Serviced By Labels</li>
        <li>Warning Boards</li>
        <li>Window Stickers</li>
    </ul>




<script type="text/javascript">

    var lis = document.getElementById("products").getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener('click', sampleChoice);
    }


    function sampleChoice() {
        document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;

    }


</script>
```

Comment: post your full code..

Comment: Full code has been added, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me

```
<ul id="products">
    <li>Bell Box Labels</li>
    <li>Camera Labels</li>
    <li>CCTV Signs</li>
    <li>Certificates & Job Books</li>
    <li>Extinguisher Labels</li>
    <li>Fascia Overlays</li>
    <li>Fire Exit Signage</li>
    <li>Panel Labels</li>
    <li>Serviced By Labels</li>
    <li>Warning Boards</li>
    <li>Window Stickers</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="resetSelection()">reset</button>
<div id="selection"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

var lis = document.getElementById("products").getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', sampleChoice);
}

var count=0;
function sampleChoice() {
    if(count<5)
        {
            document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML+= this.innerHTML;
            count++;
}}
function resetSelection()
{
    count=0;
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML= "";

}
```

Comment: Perfick, you're a saint.

Comment: What if I wanted it to only select one of the particular item instead of doubling up, as in choose only 5 from the list without duplicates?

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you for your help and now all I'd need to do is add else statements for each case to display different messages. As in 'You have selected one too many samples' and 'Only one product can be selected'.